# why http://www.google.com is an invalid host?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

i have this `nginx.conf`:

```
events {}

http {

  upstream search {
    server http://www.google.com weight=2;
    server http://www.duckduckgo.com weight=1;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;

    location /a {
      return 200 'hi';
      add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    }

    location /b {
      proxy_pass http://search;
    }
  }
}
```

when i try `sudo systemctl reload nginx` i see at `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

```
2022/06/06 16:42:55 [emerg] 576712#576712: invalid host in upstream "http://www.google.com" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:6
```

i started my exemple out of [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/loadbalanceexample/)

i tried replacing `http://www.google.com` with `http://8.8.8.8` but the error remained the same:

```
$ nginx -t
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2022/06/06 17:29:47 [emerg] 581155#581155: invalid host in upstream "http://8.8.8.8" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:6
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: You can try to replace "http://www.google.com" by 8.8.8.8 who is the of google

Comment: i've just tried, same error :(

Comment: Can u show us the result of "nginx -t" command ?

Comment: just did @LucasBodin

Comment: Can you replace "http:  //8.8.8.8" by 8.8.8.8 and test with "sudo nginx -t" ? (Stack overflow replace http:// google.com by google.com if there is no space after the http://)

Comment: removing `http://` worked! please, could you write that as an answer for me to accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since [upstream doesn't expect protocol](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#upstream), removing it made it work:

```
upstream search {
  server www.google.com weight=2;
  server www.duckduckgo.com weight=1;
}
```